# W3 Total Cache - Long TTFB when fetching css and js files

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, w3-total-cache

I am using W3 Total Cache with Wordpress and it is combining and minifing my files perfectly. However I noticed the files it creates have a long wait time (TTFB) of around 1.5 seconds when downloading compared to all other files that are under 100ms.

The files paths are like this:

```
https://www.example.com/?w3tc_minify=4ed42.css
https://www.example.com/?w3tc_minify=aae24.js
```

Is this a rewrite issue?
Is it possible to link directly to the files rather then using parameters or is this the only way W3TC works?

Where do I start looking to find the cause of this?

Notes:
Shared Hosting PHP 5.5.38

Update: I have found that I can enable "Rewrite URL structure" under the minify section of W3TC which fixes the error however when I rebuild cache or it is rebuilt automatically it removes the files and does not regenerate them so the site does not load correctly.